# creating a setup file to Netbeans java project

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

I have Java project and will making a setup file to my project. İn my procet I have a jar file which runs my project. whan can I do to create a setup file to my Netbeans Java Project

Comment: What do you mean by setup file? An installer, like http://izpack.org/?

Comment: I have an Netbeans Java Project. And I will creatin a setup file about this project so Ican Installing my project another computers. what should I do

Comment: Tahnk you.I'm sorry I wasted your time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are software convert from jar to exe like JAR2EXE but it's not setup file

Comment: Thanks. But I will creating a setup file such as mysqlsetup.exe

Comment: ok , first convert jar to exe or make executable jar from netbeans , second if you have visual studio you can easy create setup project , or search on any software can make setup file

Comment: I made executable jar . Now what must I do

Comment: http://wix.codeplex.com/ , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your interest in

Comment: Tahnk you.I'm sorry I wasted your time. :-)

Comment: never mind ,good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) which will create an Windows executable from a Java JAR file.

Comment: I can't using this program :-(

Comment: @SelçukluEbrar How come?

Comment: on which way on this program can I creating exe file from jar file?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in .Tahnk you.I'm sorry I wasted your time. :-)